# How do I create a tree system?

Tags: 7

Before I knew Drupal, I made a CMS that was working like Wikipedia, where each page and link could have parent and children. Now I want to create that website with Drupal.

Is there any module for this?

This is what I need: Each page may have children, and each children may have children too and so on.

[image: tree system]

Comment: "like Wikipedia, where each page and link could have parent and children". That doesn't sound anything like wikipedia. Wikipedia almost completely lacks hierarchical structure. Your image however appears to describe a hierarchy. If that's what you want, the book answer below is probably the easiest way to go.

Comment: @Letharion do you mean the name of Wikipedia system is not tree, and its name is hierachial

Answer (score 3):

There is a core module namely 'Book' . Use that module to get desired structure of pages.

For more information visit [here](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/book)

Comment: is it like the system what I said? I want the editor of my drupal website add information not programmer

Comment: It's important to note that Drupal has a maximum menu depth, and I believe therefore nested "pages" depth of 9 entries deep. This may or may not be a limit for you -- there may be community modules that extend this im not sure.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal you just create the pages - pages (nodes) are separate from the menu navigation system.  There are no relationships between pages until you create links in the menu system.  Use the menu to make the links to the various pages, then organize the tree relationship in the menu admin tool using drag & drop to place the navigation links in their proper structure.

Comment: na baba rast migi?